# Not able to use docxtpl in buildozer for my Kivy App

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, docxtpl

Hi I am using docxtpl to update my template file in a Kivy App. But it seems that when i specify that i am using docxtpl in requirements of buildozer.spec file it is not working. Can someone help me overcome this problem either by sharing how i can add docxtpl or any other way to update my template file. When I open the kivy app it crashes.